# Extracting Exif Metadata equivalent date and time data from Video files in Delphi or Lazarus

Tags: file, delphi, video, metadata, exif

So, my harddrive with all of my personal family photos crashed today.

I didn't want to spend several hundreds of dollars to professionally recover everything.

I managed to recover everything (I think) using Easeus data recovering software
and I coded an app that goes through every photo and extracts the
date and time Exif data and then applies it to the file date and time.

Now I have to do the same thing with the video clips.

Doesn anybody know how this can be done?
Is there any library that gives a programmer access to videofile Exif
equivalent date and time data?

Comment: You can presumably use websearch to answer your question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have done that, I can't find anything. I don't know if it's just me but I find it really hard to find answers to many of my questions. so sorry if I keep asking for things that I can't find any answers to by myself.

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything resembling an Exif section for common video file formats.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and the rest of you. You guys on here are so stingy sometimes. Why do you put my my question on hold and mark it as off topic? I would like to answer my own question please as I have found a solution to my problem and I even have programmed a fully functional software that does what I want it to do. Please open my question up again so that I can answer it!

Answer (score 1):

[`PSLookupPropertyHandlerCLSID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762084) API + `IPropertyStore` interface can provide you quick access to metadata of video/audio/image files Windows itself has capabilities to recognize.

This API is used by Explorer to populate columns in Detail view, and you can also use an application from [this post](http://alax.info/blog/1505) to quickly check a file against mentioned API, whether it is going to be helpful or not:

> Bonus tool: `FilePropertyStore` application which reads properties of the file you drag and drop onto it, [`Win32`](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Toolbox/FilePropertyStore-Win32.exe) and [`x64`](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Toolbox/FilePropertyStore-x64.exe) versions.

C++ code snippet to access properties by file path would be:

```cpp
    CLSID ClassIdentifier = CLSID_NULL;
    __C(PSLookupPropertyHandlerCLSID(CStringW(pszPath), &ClassIdentifier));
    CComPtr<IPropertyStore> pPropertyStore;
    __C(pPropertyStore.CoCreateInstance(ClassIdentifier));
    // NOTE: Initializing Property Handlers
    //       http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    const CComQIPtr<IInitializeWithStream> pInitializeWithStream = pPropertyStore;
    __D(pInitializeWithStream, E_NOINTERFACE);
    CComPtr<IStream> pStream;
    __C(SHCreateStreamOnFileEx(CStringW(pszPath), STGM_READ, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FALSE, NULL, &pStream));
    __C(pInitializeWithStream->Initialize(pStream, STGM_READ));
    DWORD nPropertyCount = 0;
    __C(pPropertyStore->GetCount(&nPropertyCount));
    // TODO: Access individual properties
```

This is not EXIF exactly, of course. EXIF values map into obtained property collections just as well as respective video file properties do. This API is also valid for still files and audio files.